# PHP array is not getting the data from mysqli query but the query works in PHPmyadmin

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to show the result of my query but I am not getting any output from the php. I have tried several different loops but I cannot get anything to show on the page. The query works in PHPmyadmin and there are no errors showing when the webpage loads. This is the code. Let me know if you need any more information. I did print_r($data) and got this result :

mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 8 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 2 [type] => 0 ) 2

```
$select = "SELECT u.`info_id`, u.`info`, u.`removed`, m.`date_added`, m.`title`, m.`summary`, m.`poster`, m.`imdb`, m.`cv` ".
            "FROM `user_movies` AS u ".
            "INNER JOIN `movies` AS m ".
            "USING (`movie_id`) ".
            "WHERE u.`user_id` = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}' ".
            "AND u.`info` = '0' AND u.`removed` = '0' ".
            "ORDER BY m.`date_added` DESC, m.`movie_id` ASC";
$data = mysqli_query($connect, $select) or die ('error getting user movies');
$movies = array();
while ($movie = mysqli_fetch_array($data));
    {       
    array_push($movies, $movie);
    }

foreach ($movies as $movie)
    {
    $id = str_replace(' ', '', $movie['title']);
    $poster = $movie['poster'];
    $title = $movie['title'];
    $summary = $movie['summary'];
    $imdb = $movie['imdb'];

    echo "<div class='movie' id='$id'><img src='$poster' alt='$title' />" .
    "<p><strong>$title</strong><br/>$summary<br/>" .
    "<a href='$imdb'title='www.imdb.com'>More info at IMDb</a></p></div>";
    }
```

Comment: Is $connect defined? Check that the connecting user has suitable permissions to run the query. What's the mysql error?

Comment: Have you echoed the query, are you sure `$_SESSION['user_id']` is set correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop had a semi colon at the end of it stopping the array_push from doing its job

```
while ($movie = mysqli_fetch_array($data));
```

should just be

```
while ($movie = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. I am presuming that you have already verified that your connection works, and that you have access to the database. I further presume that you have printed out the SELECT statement, and pasted it into PHPMyAdmin. I had done the same, and been driven crazy for a few hours.

PHPMyAdmin actually does some reformatting before it runs it. In particular, phpMyAdmin will put backticks ("`", the backwards single quote) around field names and/or table names. This is to specify that what is between the back-ticks is the name of a field of table. This is especially important if you use a reserved word as a field name. For example, if you had a field named "select", or "order", they would need back-ticks. In this particular instance, I suspect the field that you called "date". Put back-ticks around your field names and see what happens.

As a test, try removing that field from the query. Going forward, I would not use a field named "date". It is better to use something like "create_date", or "rental_date".

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I have put the select statement in PHPmyadmin and got the correct rows. I have changed the field name to date_added but it did not change anything.

Comment: Did you try putting back-ticks around all table and field names?

Comment: I tried but it did not work at all. This is what I did,             "SELECT `u.info_id`, `u.info`, `u.removed`, `m.title`, `m.summary`, `m.poster`, `m.imdb`, `m.cv` ".
    "FROM `user_movies` AS u ".
    "INNER JOIN `movies` AS m ".
    "USING (`movie_id`) ".
    "WHERE `u.user_id` = '17'".
    "AND `u.info` = '0' AND `u.removed` = '0' ".
    "ORDER BY `m.movie_id` ASC"

Comment: Thank you again for trying to help. I think I did it right this time but it didn't fix the problem.                                "SELECT u.`info_id`, u.`info`, u.`removed`, m.`title`, m.`summary`, m.`poster`, m.`imdb`, m.`cv` ".
    "FROM `user_movies` AS u ".
    "INNER JOIN `movies` AS m ".
    "USING (`movie_id`) ".
    "WHERE u.`user_id` = '17'".
    "AND u.`info` = '0' AND u.`removed` = '0' ".
    "ORDER BY m.`movie_id` ASC"

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at my question. I will start using the back-ticks around my table and field names, and use more descriptive field names.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL seems OK though in terms of style I prefer

```
            "WHERE u.user_id = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}' ".
```

My immediate Q is $_SESSION['user_id'] correctly set up because if not then the query would return zero rows.

Comment: Yes the $_SESSION is ok i have even tried putting an id directly into the query, and i have put the query in phpadmin and i get the desired information. I dont get any errors in my browser when i load the page it just shows one dive with blanks were the info is supposed to be